# Windows 10 no wifi networks visible - even the one I'm connected to

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, window, ssid

Suddenly, today, when I click on the wifi icon on the taskbar, it pops up an empty list.  There are no wifi networks visible.  Even if I go into settings and click on "list available networks", it's not showing any.

It's not even showing the one I'm connected to.  Is this a known thing?  Or something weird?

Going to do an aggressive backup of my PC just in case, and try a reboot.

Comment: Reboot sorted it, so it was "just one of those things", apparently.

Comment: Friend of mine had same thing this morning. Reboot did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems this is fixed by a reboot.  I may never know what caused it.

I was hoping this sort of nonsense was behind me.  Win10 has been pretty stable to date, this is not a development that pleases me.